# Setting the column position in printf

Tags: printf

How to fix the positions of output string in shell using `printf`?

For example ,if I want to print text `TEXT-A` at position starting from third position from left and one more text `TEXT-B` at eleventh position from left,as shown below.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
printf '  %-8s%s\n' TEXT-A TEXT-B
```

And if you want to truncate the first text if it too long to fit:

```
printf '  %-8.8s%s\n' TEXT-A TEXT-B
```